# How torch.distributed.launch assign data to each GPU?

Tags: python, pytorch

When our batch size is 1 or 2 and we have 8 GPUs, how `torch.distributed.launch` assign data to each GPUs? I converted my model to `torch.nn.parallel.DistributedDataParallel`,

```
model = DistributedDataParallel(model,
                                device_ids=[args.local_rank],
                                output_device=args.local_rank,
                                find_unused_parameters=True,
                                )
```

but it stated in the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.nn.parallel.DistributedDataParallel.html#torch.nn.parallel.DistributedDataParallel) that DistributedDataParallel:

> parallelizes the application of the given module by
> splitting the input across the specified devices by chunking in the
> batch dimension.

My question is when batch size is smaller than the number of GPUs how it deal with it?

Answer (score 1):

They don't. Unlike `Dataparallel`, the batch size you set is per-GPU. When you have 8 GPUs with batch size 1, you have an effective batch size of 8.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Does it mean that the documentation outdated?

Comment: @Amir I think they meant "effective batch size". I always thought the documentation for DDP is confusing. The key is to recognize that there will be one main Python process for each GPU -- each doing its data loading and loss computation -- and communicate only through `DistributedDataParallel` and `DistributedSampler`.